# MySQL create table fails due to foreignkey

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

This seems to be a very common problem but I can't seem to find an answer despite of all the posts and pseudotutorials I have read in the last 2 days :/

The project I am currently working on forces me to learn how to use MySQL and I seem to have run into a problem concerning ForeignKeys or Indexes.

> > I have these creates: 
> >      http://paste.ubuntu.com/1503473/

Edit: Inserting crutial part here cause the link above might die sometime:

```
   CREATE TABLE user_book (
        userid  Varbinary(16),
        bookid Varbinary(16),

        PRIMARY KEY(userid, bookid),

        INDEX(userid),
        FOREIGN KEY(userid)  REFERENCES user,

        INDEX (bookid),
        FOREIGN KEY(bookid) REFERENCES book

    )ENGINE=INNODB;

    Made the same mistake at user_chapter.
```

But sql throws an error at Table "user_book": 
 #1005 - Can't create table 'mangressdb.user_book' (errno: 150)

It would be really great if you could help me out here as I am close to crying. It is probably just a very stupid mistake on my part but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are getting name conflicts in your DDL. Try explicitly specifying the parent table columns to be used for the foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE user_book (
    userid  Varbinary(16),
    bookid Varbinary(16),

    PRIMARY KEY(userid, bookid),

    INDEX(userid),
    FOREIGN KEY(userid)  REFERENCES user (userid),

    INDEX (bookid),
    FOREIGN KEY(bookid) REFERENCES book (bookid)

)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You will need to also explicitly specify the parent column names for your `user_chapter` table.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem! Thanks a lot! I renamed the columns and it worked! But you said something about specifying the table? Could you please tell me how to do that? book.bookid doesn't seen to work..

Comment: Nope, you do not need any additional specification but for the columns. Sorry if that wasn't clear from my example. Glad to hear its working for you now!

Comment: Oh my god! How could I have missed that! I probably read through the code a 100 times. It seems that I only ask questions here to embarrass  myself ^^" But a GREAT THANKS to you!